# Calculate Age Range and parttime share in R

Tags: r, share

I am new in R, so my experience is quite low. I have a question please:

I have to calculate in which age range the share of part-time employment is the highest.
I have two variables: parttime, which equals 1 if the individual is working parttime, and 0 if the individual is working full-time (***note***: this variable is only defined for those in employment).

the variable age_intervals is equal to 1 if individual is between 25 and 29 y.o., 2 if the individual is 30-34 y.o., and so on. I have tried that:

`parttime_share <- data_R_age_inter %>% group_by(data_R_age_inter$age_inter) %>% summarise(parttime_share = mean(parttime)) View(parttime_share)`

but it gives me *NA* for all variables.
Could anyone help me please?

Thanks.
Michael

I don't have what I was expecting to have. So, probably computational errors.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(age_intervals) %>% 
  summarise(parttime_share = mean(parttime, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  age_intervals parttime_share
          <dbl>          <dbl>
1             1            1  
2             2            0.5
3             3            1
```

Two things here: (i) in `dplyr` syntax you do not (have to) repeat the data frame's name each time you perform an operation; you just rfer to the variables; (ii) when calculating the mean it is good advice to always include the argument `na.rm = TRUE` because otherwise if there are `NA` values, the mean will always be returned as `NA`.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  parttime = c(1,NA,1,0,1,1,1),
  age_intervals = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3)
)
```